# Is there an way to rotate a specific window from terminal?

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal, customization, c, xdotool

I am using cava music player.So since cava by default appears horizontally , i wanted to change the orientation how cava appears to vertical or tilt the window so that it appears vertical.Is there any way to do this?Is there a way to rotate my terminal window?
Edit:I have ubuntu 18.04 with oh my bash installed in terminal

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: I am using ubuntu 18.04